# Bitwarden на всех поддоменах вместо одного

Tags: docker

Поставил bitwarden на vps. При установке указал один поддомен
Однако после установки bitwarden открывается и на втором поддомене
Лазил в настройки config.yml но победить так и не смог.
Я хочу чтобы в итоге на одном поддомене открывался bitwarden, а на другом другой сайт
Кто-нибудь настраивал такое?

Comment: Начинаем с самого начала - кто конкретно слушает порты 80 и 443?

Answer (score -1):

Собственно дело в управлении докер контейнерами. Решение в использовании Traefik или что-то подобноe.